# Configuring eslint and jslint to not give errors with reserved react-native keywords like [import,export]

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, jslint, brackets

I am very new to react native. I decided to learn on brackets text editor but when I opened the default template in app.js file, eslint and jslint complain about reserved keywords like import and export.
I tried to change the configuration of eslint in node-modules directory but it did not work. I tried also to change in the .eslintrc.js file but found a lot of them and did not know which one to modify.

Here is a picture to see the errors

[image]

Comment: In terms of the location of the `.eslintrc` file this should be in your project root. ESLint looks for it outwards from the location of the file it should be applied to so if you have other `.eslintrc` in inner directories they might override the one in the root directory.

Comment: yes,there are .eslint.js files everywhere .. i just don't know what i do as I need to fix this issue because it is messing up the text format

Comment: As far as I know the configuration is in `.eslintrc`; I don't know about `.eslintrc.js`